# How to handle comma separated decimal values in Hive?

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform, decimal-point

I have one CSV file and metadata for the same. Columns in this CSV is are delimited by pipe | symbol. Sample data is as follows:

```
name|address|age|salary|doj
xyz | abcdef|29 |567,34|12/02/2001
```

Here `salary` column is of type decimal but instead of using `period .` as decimal separator, `comma ,` is used.

I created Hive external table as below and for this data Hive shows `NULL` for `salary` column.

```
create external table employee as(
      name string,
      address string,
      age int,
      salary decimal(7,3),
      doj string
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LOCATION 's3://bucket/folder_having_many_csv_files/';
```

If I change data type of `salary` column to `String` then as expected, Hive works fine.

I would like to know how to tell Hive that this particular column is of type `DECIMAL` and decimal separator is `comma (,)` and not a `period (.)` symbol.

Comment: Any reason you can't just replace the comma separators in the file with decimals?

Comment: These files are huge, dumped by other team. I can write some map-reduce program or Spark to replace comma separators but before doing that I wanted to check if there is something in Hive which I can use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could easily build table with salary as a string and replace the comma in a view on top.  This is probably the easiest thing to do since the data is big and likely someone else owns it.

```
create view table employee_decimal as
 select name
  , address
  , age
  , cast(regexp_replace(salary, ',', '.') as decimal(7,3)) as salary
  , doj
 from employee;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is easy way.