# Error when use semicolon delimiter in AWS ATHENA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, delimiter

I created the table below with ';' delimiter, but in the column 'value' it only appears numbers without 'comma', numbers with comma doesn't appear.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table` (
  `value` double,
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

```
Inside CSV: | output:
  value        value
    24          24.0
    24,96
```

```
Expect:
Inside CSV: | output:
  value        value
    24          24.0
    24,96       24.96
```

Comment: had this issue when working with french localization, seperator was considered comma, maybe similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41246004/how-to-handle-comma-separated-decimal-values-in-hive

Comment: Consider using pipe '|' as delimiter.